# Recreating Ink in water effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, ink

Does anyone know how to create this in Illustrator? I contacted the person who made it but the gave me a very vague answer like a bunch of selections but they never gave me an idea of how to actually create something like this. I tried searching for tutorials but all I found was simplistic versions that didn't get the look I was going for.

Does anyone know how to create this?

[image]

*Update by Ryan:*

I don't have the exact one Lulu asked about but here's some screen grabs of the one I do have so people will stop saying its not vector:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The background image of the "ink in water" is probably a photograph. Are you sure someone made this instead of taking a photograph?

Comment: It's vector @AndrewH -- I'm not seeing this exact one but http://www.shutterstock.com/g/Markovka/sets/1950216 ..... Lulu, I know I made the mistake of buying one of these to use in a client's ad. It worked for sure but its not nearly as nice as you think from the images on Shutterstock. Probably would've been better off purchasing an isolated JPG/TIFF instead unless you absolutely need a ridiculously large size. As for how it was made, not sure. I can check the file again this evening though and see - may have just been auto traced.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried it on a random image of ink in water from Alberto Seveso's [high speed ink in water](http://twistedsifter.com/2013/04/high-speed-photographs-of-ink-dropped-into-water/) and to me it looks like what the people on Shutterstock are probably doing is either taking a high speed photograph or purchasing one and then using Adobe Illustrator Autotrace:

[image]

[image]

If you have the camera or could hire someone especially with like a Medium Format and then experiment with the technique yourself you could get better results from a photograph for sure, its just a matter of having the ability to take the high speed photo and with a camera high enough resolution for whatever size you need

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With some insane amount of work could be done in ilustrator, with some real life photos for reference.

Here is a first attempt using a **Mesh fill** on Corel. But as you can see this will become extremely complex...

[image]

But they are a heck more easily done taking a photo... you guessed... Ink on a water tank.

https://www.google.com/search?q=ink+on+a+tank+photo+tutorial

They also can be done in 3D with a specialized **particle generator** and render engine: https://www.afterworks.com/FumeFX/Overview.asp

or try blender

- https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=blender+smoke
- https://www.blender.org/manual/pt/physics/smoke/index.html

I really would not waste time doing it natively in Illustrator. Of course, you can vectorize it or trace it after you have a base image. But... That is cheating :o).

Answer (score 2):

I would create it in Photoshop, not Illustrator. Obviously, Photoshop won't give you vector art, but the transparency effects shown aren't really suited to vector output.

Search for custom Photoshop brushes. [These brushes](http://mixclipart.com/ink-in-water-free-photoshop-brushes/) look like they might do what you're looking for